# Know EC2 Instances by region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to know EC2 instances by region from aws-cli?

Desired output:

```
Region name      name 
us-west-1         instance1
us-west-1         instance2
us-west-2         instance1
us-east-1         instance1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good starting point for a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

all_regions="us-east-1 us-east-2 us-west-1 us-west-2"

echo "Region Name     Instance ID"
for region in ${all_regions}; do
  aws ec2 describe-instances --region ${region} | \
    grep '"InstanceId":' | \
    perl -pe "s/.*: \"(i-.*?)\".*/${region}       \1/"
done
```

The *aws* command above is the AWS command line interface:

https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

*describe-instances* is one of the commands for the AWS CLI:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html

*grep* and *perl* are standard utilities.

Comment: I took your script and change the line all_regions="us-east-1 us-east-2 us-west-1 us-west-2" to a dynamic content `all_regions=$(aws ec2 describe-regions | grep '"RegionName":' | perl -pe "s/.*: \"(.*?)\".*/ \1/")`        describe-regions is another command for the AWS CLI [link] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-regions.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can only list instances via the CLI from one region at a time. So you would write a script that loops through each region, getting the instances in each region.